# Suppose $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is complete as metric space, then, how can I prove $ \Bbb{Q}_p$(defined as fraction field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$) is also complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is complete as metric space, then, how can I prove $ \Bbb{Q}_p$(defined as fraction field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$) is also complete ?

My try

Suppose {$a_n$} be caushy sequence in $\Bbb{Q}_p$.
{$p^na_n$} is Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for some $n$.
{$p^na_n$} has limit point $α$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, hence {$a_n$} converges to $α/p^n$.
So,$\Bbb{Q}_p$ is complete.

Comment: Looks good to me. You might want to give an argument why such an $n$ exists.

Comment: You seem to be using $n$ for two different things: the index of the sequence $(a_n)$, and the power of $p$ you're multiplying by. Presumably you mean: choose some $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $p^m a_n \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $n$.